# creating custom tag libs for UI components

Tags: jsf, taglib

I'm creating custom tag libraries that will have the core JSF UI components embedded in them which will essentially render the UI components with added behavior to the out-of--provided components. For example I have a tablib ST.xhtml file like this

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value.ST.value}" rendered="#{readonly!='true'}" style="#{style}" required="#{required}" requiredMessage="#{requiredMessage}" /><br/>
    <h:panelGroup id="#{id}Error" style="display:none;color:#EE0000;font-style:italic;" >
        x
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{value.ST.value}" rendered="#{readonly=='true'}" />
</ui:composition>
```

this is used to create a HTML input text field on the page. The code to use this component will look like this

```
<trim:ST value="#{myBean.property}" style="color:red"/>
```

As you see this approach doesn't work well if I want to set new attributes to the underlying UI component from my JSF page. For example if I want to add an onclick event handler to `h:inputText` I have to change the taglib definition to set the attribute from the caller. I don't like this approach because I would have to define each and every attribute in taglib to be able to use it from my JSF pages. Does anybody any solution to this?